# Error Initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[Android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbje.png)
[No device detected on windows 7 computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeLur.png)

[Drivers are installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ6LZ.png)
[ADB devices also shows a list of connected devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaUfE.png)

```
Steps tried:
[1.] Usb debugging is on 
[2.] Phone is recognized by windows 7 but not able to see in android studio.
[3.] Tried changing different usb.
[4.] Installed google usb and samsung usb drivers.
[5.] Tried changing MTP to PTP but did not worked.
[6.] Restarted Android Studio couple of times still not working.
```

Comment: Do you tried to kill and restart adb from android studio terminal adb kill-server and adb start-server

Comment: did that still not working...